# How to print timestamp of a packet read from pcap file?

Tags: c, formatting, timestamp, packet, libpcap

I am trying to read the packets from a pcap file using a c program and print the time-stamp of each packet.

I am using the below line of code to print the timestamp:

```
printf("%s,",ctime((const time_t*)&header->ts.tv_sec));
```

And my output is as below:

```
Mon Jan 14 09:48:18 2013
```

How do I get it as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS like the one shown below?

```
2016-02-16 13:14:33.224487
```

I am new to c programming and have no clue what i am doing. Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: 2013, really? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like to have a look at [`localtime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3p.html) and [`strftime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html).

```
#define MYDATE_STR_MAX (<large enough> + 1)

...

  struct tm lt = localtime(header->ts.tv_sec);
  char st[MYDATE_STR_MAX];
  strftime(st, MYDATE_STR_MAX, <format specifier as per man-page here>, lt);
  /* use st here */
```

(include `<time.h>` on top)

Comment: It worked. I used   strftime(buff,20,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));

Comment: Missing `max` parameter to strftime ;)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Ouch ... - fixed.